# Got my points reduced on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, answers, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I delete my answer, then are the points achieved on that answer from votes deducted from my reputation?

If someone has changed their accepted answer, then are the points for my correct answer also deducted?

Comment: Obviously yes.. You really need to look at [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/187824)

Comment: @hsuk Any specific reason for the unaccept? Just curious.

Comment: tried deleting the question as it seems to be too obvious, could not delete, so tried by deselecting the answer again, never mind

Comment: @hsuk - FYI: You could not delete it because it has a upvoted answer. Have a look at [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/187824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete your own question, the reputation change from that question is reversed. If someone else changes their best answer away from your answer, you lose the `+15` reputation from it.

Stackoverflow has, with a couple exceptions here and there, a rolling reputation calculation. Reputation is added and subtracted from your total as you accumulate it, and as such, if you delete a question, your reputation gain/loss is reverted.

See also: [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

- `one of your accepted answers loses accepted status: −15`